# Flask File upload to Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: python-3.x, azure-data-lake, flask-restful

I am trying to upload a file from a Flask (Flask-restplus) application directly to azure data lake store (gen1).

The flask application is running on azure web app.  Is that even possible, or would I need to upload it to the azure web app server first, before moving it to ADLS?

The python library for ADLS (https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-python) doesn't seem to have any function for that. For example, `ADLUploader` expects a local file as source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No direct way for that.

One way is that as you mentioned, upload to app server, then move to ADLS.

Another possible way is that if you can `convert the file content to bytes`, then you can use some other methods in ADLS like `open() / write()`, details like below(just the Pseudocode, you can modify them as per your need):

1.Create a client: `myclient = core.AzureDLFileSystem(adlCreds,store_name=adlsAccountName)`

2.Get the file name you're uploading, create an empty file in ADLS: `myclient.touch("test/myfile.txt")`

3.Open the file in ADLS with 'wb' mode: `myfile = myclient.open('test/myfile.txt','wb')`

4.Use some methods to convert the content of the file you're uploading to bytes

5.Use write() and flush() method to write the bytes content to the files in ADLS:

```
myfile.write(in_file.read()) #the content should be bytes
myfile.flush(force=True)
```

Comment: That's in fact a great idea. I went for it, and it works. I'll next test with a bigger file.